# php Auto fill form not filling with MySQL table data but with table ID number

Tags: php, mysql, autofill

I am trying to make my table auto fill information from the MySQL database using PHP but it is auto filling all the form spaces with the number 1. The number is the ID number of that particular product that I selected to edit on the previous webpage. I have shortened the form so there isn't as much code to look at.

```
<?php

   //Check that a product ID is specified for the page
    if (isset($_GET['ItemID'])) {
        $productID = $_GET['ItemID'];
   }else{
        header("Location: ../update.php");
   }

    if (isset($_POST['Name'])) {
       $Name = $_POST['Name'];
       $Description = $_POST['Description'];

      $updateQuery = "
UPDATE item 
   SET name = '$Name'
     , Description = '$Description' 
 WHERE condition = '$Description' 
 WHERE ID= $productID";

     $mysqli->query($updateQuery);
     echo ("Product successfully updated"); 
   }


    $query = "
SELECT * 
  FROM item 
 WHERE ItemID = $productID
";
    $result = $mysqli->query($query);

  if($result->num_rows > 0) {
        $data = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_BOTH);


?>

 <h2> Edit Product </h2>
 <form action="edit.php?ItemID=<?php echo ($productID); ?>" method="POST" >
        <fieldset>
            <h4>Sell Your Item</h4>
            <p><label class="title" for="Name">Name:</label>
            <input type="text" placeholder="<?php echo ($productID); ?>" name="Name" id="Name" title="Please enter item name" 
            ><br />

            <label class="title" for="Description">Description:</label>
            <textarea name="Description" rows="5" cols="33" placeholder="<?php echo ($productID); ?>"  id="Description" title="Please describe your item" >
  </textarea><br />
  </fieldset>
  </form>

 <?php 
   }
  ?>
```

Comment: print the value of `$_GET['ItemID']` or `$productID`before using it on form

Comment: both are still leaving the me with the same result of having 1 in every form field

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but worth mentioning: This code is prone to SQL injection and can be exploited easily.

Comment: You really can't see anything wrong here?